# Find My Friends shows my old phone

Tags: iphone, icloud

I traded in my 4S recently to upgrade to a 5S, and restored the 5S from the last 4S backup, so they both share the same phone name ("Adam's iPhone"). However, when I use the "Find My Friends" app, it displays "Share my location from:" and shows "Adam's iPhone" twice.

I visited [this Apple Support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph2702), which suggested to log into iCloud and disable the second phone from there, but only one phone is listed on that page (along with my iPad and iMac). Is there another link that explains how to remove the old phone from "Find My Friends"?

Comment: Open up the Find iPhone app (not Find Friends). Are both of the phones listed there?

Comment: @ChrisMukherjee - no, just the 5S.

Answer (score 7):

I found the way to do it on iOS 8:
Settings > Privacy > Location Services > Share My Location > From

Then is will show the list of current and old phones.  It has instructions:  "If you're no longer using a device, swipe left on the device name, then tap Delete."

It worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what's on that Apple page, here's what's going on: Your two devices have the same name, so you need to change the name of the iPhone 5S: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3965

Once you see the both devices showing on iCloud with different names, then you should be able to 'eliminate' the other device per the instructions on that [page on removing Apple devices from 'Find My...'](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph2702).

Tech aside: Different UDIDs, same 'device name' causes headaches...

Comment: That is all correct, except that only one iPhone shows up in the OP's Find My iPhone account.

Comment: He has to change the names because iCloud may only 'list' *one* 'named' device... even tho' it *should* be smart enough to list 2 devices with 2 different UDIDs. Also, iCloud may have to be kicked (on-off) cycles a number of times. 2 problems here: Find My iPhone's handling of 'names'... and crappy iCloud sync.

Comment: I renamed the phone, and I will try this tonight. Thanks!

Comment: @leoofborg Ahhh I see.

Answer (score 1):

had same issue tried all hove. went into settings and location services and i noticed i had find my friend app unchecked needs to be checked to locate

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and I can say that iCloud does show duplicate names for different devices with the same name.  Furthermore, removing the old device from iCloud still leaves it displayed in the Find Friends app.

However, removing it from Privacy > Location Services > My Devices takes care of it.